# Tutorials on Microsoft Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio

I downloaded Visual Studio installer from Microsoft site and I have use the downloadball, then install feature to installed the ASP.NET features.

My question is that, where did the setup files stores to? I just want to know if possible I format my PC in order to install it without re downloading the files again.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you choose during the installation.

Usually, the packages are put in drive_letter:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages.

That is true, only if you check during the installation 'Keep download cache', see the image below.

[image]

See more on [Use command-line parameters to install Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/use-command-line-parameters-to-install-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)
and [Select the installation locations in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/change-installation-locations?view=vs-2019)